# Retrieve value from xml response in java

Tags: java, xml, request, response

I have an XML response like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns6:ReadPersonReturn xmlns:ns2="urn:co-base.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns1="urn:cs-base.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns4="urn:co-meta.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns3="urn:co-ors.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns5="urn:task-base.informatica.mdm" xmlns:ns6="urn:cs-ors.informatica.mdm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns6:ReadPersonReturn">
   <ns6:object xmlns:ns0="urn:cs-rest.informatica.mdm">
      <ns3:Person label="Person">
         <ns2:rowidObject>28</ns2:rowidObject>
         <ns3:firstNM>John</ns3:firstNM>
         <ns3:lastNM>Cook</ns3:lastNM>
         <ns3:Phone firstRecord="1" pageSize="10" searchToken="SVR1.28WC2">
            <ns3:item label="Phone">
               <ns2:rowidObject>1</ns2:rowidObject>
               <ns3:phoneNumber>123456789</ns3:phoneNumber>
            </ns3:item>
         </ns3:Phone>
      </ns3:Person>
      <ns3:changeSummary logging="false" xmlns:sdo="commonj.sdo"/>
   </ns6:object>
</ns6:ReadPersonReturn>
```

I am able to print the first name or last name like below:

```
System.out.println(readResponse.getString("object/Person/firstNM"));
System.out.println(readResponse.getString("object/Person/lastNM"));
```

but not able to print the phone number with the following piece of code:

```
System.out.println(readResponse.getString("object/Person/Phone/phoneNumber"));
```

How do I get the value for `<ns3:phoneNumber>`?

Comment: Never traversed XML as you posted, but I think `readResponse.getString("object/Person/Phone/item/phoneNumber")` may give you desired result

Comment: Thanks for the help. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never traversed XML as you posted, but I think

`readResponse.getString("object/Person/Phone/item/phoneNumber");`

may give you desired result.